# Styles are not applied material UI + Next JS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

My custom styles are overwritten by the global ones.
I am using material ui and next js.

Answer (score 2):

**prepend: true should be added**

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/mui/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs?file=/src/createEmotionCache.js:0-331

```
import createCache from '@emotion/cache';

// prepend: true moves MUI styles to the top of the <head> so they're loaded first.
// It allows developers to easily override MUI styles with other styling solutions, like CSS modules.
export default function createEmotionCache() {
  return createCache({ key: 'css', **prepend: true** });
}
```

Comment: I was looking for this answer right now. Thanks man! :) I spent an entire day searching for this.